# Extended members picker control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, umbraco

Is there a way to make the member picker dropdown list show only to members of a certain group or type?

Currently we have the dropdown lists showing all the members in the database (around 10k users).

I need a way to do it without losing any of my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to create a custom datatype that allows you to have a different type of member picker - [this is a good guide to creating a custom datatype in Umbraco](http://www.nibble.be/?p=24) and how you then are able to use it in Umbraco to replace the default member picker.

As to getting a subset of members [there are good tips on our.umbraco.org](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/16044-Getting-all-Members-in-a-Membergroup) along the lines of:

```
var list = MemberGroup.GetByName("Member Group Name").GetMembersAsIds();
```

I guess if you wanted to have a dropdown in your custom datatype you could bind a selectbox to a Dictionary coded like (not tested, but adapted from another code snippet):

```
Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var memberGroup = MemberGroup.GetByName("Member Group Name");
if (memberGroup != null)
{
        foreach (Member member in memberGroup.GetMembers())
        {
                list.Add(member.Id, member.Name);
        }
}
```

On the level two training there is a worked example on using an autocomplete field to allow member picking by entering part of their name - so if you create a custom datatype you might want to evaluate whether the dropdown is the correct UI element for your needs.

Comment: is there are reason you wouldn't use MemberGroup.GetByName("").GetMembers() to get all members of a certain group?

Comment: Sounds like a good method to use as long as you check that the resultant list isn't empty or null before processing.  Both techniques will result in the same amount of internal processing.